# update existing infrastructure on heroku using terraform

Tags: heroku, terraform

I've got this infrastructure description

```
variable "HEROKU_API_KEY" {}

provider "heroku" {
    email = "sebastrident@gmail.com"
    api_key = "${var.HEROKU_API_KEY}"
}

resource "heroku_app" "default" {
    name = "judge-re"
    region = "us"
}
```

Originally I forgot to specify `buildpack`. It created the application on heroku. I decided to add it to `resource` entry

```
    buildpacks = [
        "heroku/java"
    ]
```

But when I try to apply the plan in `terraform` I get this error

```
Error: Error applying plan:
1 error(s) occurred:
* heroku_app.default: 1 error(s) occurred:
* heroku_app.default: Post https://api.heroku.com/apps: Name is already taken
Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

Terraform plan looks like this

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + heroku_app.judge_re
      id:                <computed>
      all_config_vars.%: <computed>
      buildpacks.#:      "1"
      buildpacks.0:      "heroku/java"
      config_vars.#:     <computed>
      git_url:           <computed>
      heroku_hostname:   <computed>
      name:              "judge-re"
      region:            "us"
      stack:             <computed>
      web_url:           <computed>


Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.
```

As a workaround I tried to add `destroy` in my `deploy.sh` script

```
terraform init
terraform plan

terraform destroy -force

terraform apply -auto-approve
```

But it does not destroy the resource as I get the message `Destroy complete! Resources: 0 destroyed.`

What is the problem?

Link to [build](https://travis-ci.org/lapots/judge-rule-engine/builds/342999033)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you also changed the name of the resource. Your original example has the resource name `heroku_app.default` while your plan has `heroku_app.judge_re`.

To point your state to the remote resource, so Terraform knows you are editing and not trying to recreate the resource, use `terraform import`:

`terraform import heroku_app.judge_re judge-re`

Answer (score 0):

In terraform, normally you needn't destroy the whole stack, which you just want to re-build one or several resources in it.

[terraform taint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/taint.html) does this trick.  The terraform taint command manually marks a Terraform-managed resource as tainted, forcing it to be destroyed and recreated on the next apply.

```
terraform taint heroku_app.default
```

Second, when you troubleshooting why the resource isn't list in destroy resource, please make sure you point to the right terraform tfstate file.

when you run `terraform plan`, did you see any resources which already was created?

Comment: yeah, it seemed strange to me that I needed to destroy the stack. I presumed that there should a be command to update the stack instead of destroying it. So usually `taint` is used instead of `destroy`?

Comment: "when you run terraform plan, did you see any resources which already was created" what do you mean by that? it just showed `terraform will perform the following actions` with the list of resource parameters

Comment: If you point to right tfstate file, and run with `terraform plan`, you should see the resources which are created and a list which will be created/updated/or deleted. Did you get any thing, can you update in your original question with the output of  `terraform plan`?

Comment: But I don't have `tfstate` file. Update with `plan`

Comment: It seems I have some other problem. When I try to create and delete from local machine it works fine.